# How are things such as evil eyes/dark attachments/evil handled in Jewish tradition?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, evil-resha, superstition, ayin-hara-evil-eye

While the topic isn't discussed heavily in modern Judaism (outside of the evil inclination) the idea that there are dark forces which can negatively impact and overwhelm individuals is a very real part of the mystical traditions.

I was curious as to how the Rabbis handled such situations and if there were processes that individuals had to undergo to remove dark forces and evil eyes and such.

Comment: By "the mystical traditions" do you mean Jewish mystical traditions?

Comment: This likely seems too broad.

Comment: Whether or not you believe in dark forces, all streams of Judaism agree that God is the ultimate power. It is similarly accepted that Man can speak directly to God, and needs no intermediaries. Accordingly, one can always simply ask God for help. If He wants, he can help with or without occult hocus pocus,

Comment: Given that this question seems like the sort of question that could have a whole book written to answer it, I would recommend asking for resources (such as books or articles) that discuss the range of rabbinic approaches to such things.